# RadioGroupFieldEditor setPropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, swt

I have a `RadioGroupFieldEditor` field in my application, this field is internally added to `FieldEditorPreferencePage` using `addField()` method.

I have added `setPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener()` for the field, but the control is not going to `IPropertyChangeListener` when I select the value.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `FieldEditorPreferencePage` already implements the `IPropertyChangeListener` interface and gets sets as the listener for every FieldEditor that you add to the PreferencePage. Simply override the `propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)` method. Don't forget to call `super.propertyChange(event)` in there, as it checks for certain events.